# A list within a list using Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

What is the correct format to have many variables that contains a list within a list for React.

The following code is what I have and it seems to work. I just wanted to double check.

```
const mainObject = [
  {
    Object1: [
      {
        id: 1,
        linkto: "#Home",
        linkname: "Home"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        linkto: "#Experience",
        linkname: "Experience"
      }
    ],
    Object2: [
      {       
        id: 1,
        linkto: "#Home",
        linkname: "Home"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        linkto: "#Experience",
        linkname: "Experience"
      }
    ]
  }
];

export default mainObject;
```

Comment: What is the point of the outer array? It only has one object in it, so could be taken away entirely. Also, why do the inner objects need `id` if you need to know it's index to grab it anyway? It's `id` could just be it's index position +1.

Comment: you can simply have array of array.

Comment: I think your code is fine. This is exactly how to have lists with a lists.

Comment: I think it is fine. You can also use a double array. You can also get rid of outer array and have key whose value is an array. You can loop through keys for outer array.

Comment: No need for the object1, object 2 etc. You are creating deep structure not needed. See my answer below for better way.

Answer (score 0):

No need to mention object 1, object 2, etc. They are already objects within the array.

```
    const mainObject = [
          {
            id: 1,
            linkto: "#Home",
            linkname: "Home"
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            linkto: "#Experience",
            linkname: "Experience"
          },
          {       
            id: 1,
            linkto: "#Home",
            linkname: "Home"
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            linkto: "#Experience",
            linkname: "Experience"
          }
    ];

    export default mainObject;
```

You can use `map`to loop over and do some operation on each object in the array. In react you will do something like this:

```
mainObject.map((obj)=> {
    console.log(obj);
    return <li key={obj.id}><a href={obj.linkto}>{obj.linkname}</a>
});

// With implicit return
mainObject.map((obj)=> <li key={obj.id}><a href={obj.linkto}>{obj.linkname}</a>);
```

Comment: I understand why you did it this way, but this was only as an example. I presented this way to make it easy to explain. I want to learn how to use it for future nested complex objects.

Comment: Ok I understand, so are you still looking for an answer? Or you know what to do?

Comment: I know what to do. I think the verification from Osama Khalid took care of it. I appreciate your help though.